# Python Script Execution on Server

Tags: python, html, heroku, web-development-server

**Objective**:

- My goal is to enable a file-upload of a picture, where a Python Script that I wrote uses a computerVision model to recognize certain objects in the uploaded picture and store the outcome over the script in a CSV file.
- This Information would at a later point in time be accessed by an HTML Script from a different server for conversations with a chatbot (Api.AI)

**What I did so far:**

- I was recommended to create a Heroku application that implemented this Script.
- Related to that, I have been trying for the past two days to solve an issue with the installing of dependencies via pip (on a Ubuntu VM) in the projects virtual-env, but was so far unable to solve it.
- Before this, I tried the same on Windows, but other problems that came up in the process forced me to change to a different OS for the web server
- Overall I have been working on this Problem for a month, most time spent trying to figure out how to implement the working script that I have in a Heroku App.

**My Question:**

- I looked almost everywhere for a solution to the problems that I am encountering and so far nothing seems to work.
- Overall I'd be happy if there was another way to achieve my objective since I have so far experienced more setbacks with Heroku than achievements. I know that getting experience takes time, but I do have a deadline that I need to stick to. So if anyone knows a better way to achieve the objective that I currently have (preferably without Heroku), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you outline a bit clearer what the actual problem is? Is it with one of your scripts or with installing dependencies you need for your script? The only thing I can read out of your question is that something with heroku is not working.

Comment: Apologies, that was merely meant as an outline as to what I am trying to do.The main question is whether anybody knows maybe a better way to use a Script in the manner that I am going for, without the use of Heroku. Or whether creating a Heroku application is already a good possible solution to achieving the objective.